# Centos 6 PHP 5.3.29 from IUS with httpd 2.4. from IUS too

Tags: centos, php, apache-2.4

I have old depracated linux Centos6 machines for old SW. We need PHP 5.3. for customers. I'd like use this machines for newer versions PHP with FPM - and migrate to htpd 2.4. and FPM for PHP 5.3 too.

Problem is with compatibility. I run

```
yum replace httpd --replace-with=httpd24u
```

But I get this in summary:

```
Removing for dependencies:
php53u x86_64 5.3.29-1.ius.el6 @ius-archive                         4.4 M
php53u-fpm x86_64 5.3.29-1.ius.el6 @ius-archive                         4.0 M
```

I need stay with php53u. I think, that it is safe because with FPM I will without some dependencie on Apache.

Can you help me what I can do with this?

Answer (score 1):

php53u is the Apache module for PHP, commonly known as mod_php.  It links against the stock version of httpd, and thus cannot stay installed with httpd24u, which replaces the stock httpd.

IUS packages are designed to replace their stock equivalents.  If you need multiple versions of PHP or Apache installed, software collections are what you are looking for.

https://ius.io/faq#how-is-ius-different-from-scl